# Is there any option to connect to Azure Tables to store and retrieve data from Camel?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

We have a requirement to connect to Azure Table storage to store and retrieve the data . When i checked the documentation it supports only blob , Queue and File storage.

One option i can see is using the CDATA but looks like its paid

Please do let know if there any other option we can use for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Azure Table storage is a service that stores structured NoSQL data in the cloud, providing a key/attribute store with a schemaless design.

It's true if you have a java application using *that uses Apache Camel routing* then the best choice would be to use the *CData JDBC Driver* to work on Azure Tables.

Generally we use **Azure Tables client library** for Java Application to create tables, store your data, and perform CRUD operations on said data. Here you configure your app to access Table Storage by adding the following entry to your *pom.xml* file's `dependencies` section :

```java
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
  <artifactId>azure-data-tables</artifactId>
  <version>12.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Then, add the following `import` statements to the top of the Java file where you want to use Azure Tables APIs to access tables.

```java
// Include the following imports to use table APIs
import com.azure.data.tables.TableClient;
import com.azure.data.tables.TableClientBuilder;
import com.azure.data.tables.TableServiceClient;
import com.azure.data.tables.TableServiceClientBuilder;
import com.azure.data.tables.models.ListEntitiesOptions;
import com.azure.data.tables.models.TableEntity;
import com.azure.data.tables.models.TableEntityUpdateMode;
import com.azure.data.tables.models.TableTransactionAction;
import com.azure.data.tables.models.TableTransactionActionType;
```

Alternatively, you can also use the **Cosmos DB with the Camel** which is also stores structured NoSQL data in the cloud. There is also the [AZURE COSMOSDB](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.11.x/azure-cosmosdb-component.html) document at Camel website which explains its components. So you can also use Cosmos DB Table API in your Java application.

Read the [How to use the Azure Tables client library for Java](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/table/how-to-use-java#configure-your-app-to-access-table-storage) document for more detailed information on how to use Table API and Cosmos DB API with Java.